# Get custom payload of push notification while app is running background

Tags: iphone, ipad, background, push-notification, payload

Hey can anybody tell how to get custom payload of push notification when app is in background?

If your app is in the background and you receive a push notification and the user taps app "View", the application is launched and `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` would get called. In this case we can access custom notification payload via  `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` from `userInfo` dictionary.

If your app is in the background and you receive a push notification and the user taps app icon, it brings the application to the foreground.

When that happens, only `applicationDidEnterForeground:` is called, and there is no way to access the payload of the push notification.

My requirement is to register for Badge only, no alert so no 'View' button to launch app when user receives notification in background. When user receives notification and application is in background, user taps app icon `applicationDidEnterForeground:` is called. So we have no way to access `launchOptions` dictionary or `userInfo` dictionary from where we can get notification payload.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7):

`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is called when the user taps on the notification in the statusbar drop down if your app is running in the background.  The [link you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167614/ios-handling-pushed-notifications-with-apns) in your answer explains how to use it.